# How to pass data from all_product.js to ShopCategory.jsx using React Context?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, react-context

I Want to pass `allproduct` in 'Shopcategory.jsx' using `ShopContext`, but there is nothing showing while selecting each category when I am trying this.

## ShopContext.jsx

```
import React, { createContext } from "react";
import all_product from "../Components/Assets/all_product";

export const ShopContext = createContext(null);

const ShopContextProvider = (props) => {
    const contextValue = {all_product};

    return(
        <ShopContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
            {props.children}
        </ShopContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default ShopContextProvider;
```

## ShopCategory.jsx

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import './CSS/ShopCategory.css';
import { ShopContext } from "../Context/ShopContext"
import dropdown_icon from '../Components/Assets/dropdown_icon.png';
import { Item } from '../Components/Item/Item';

const ShopCategory = (props) => {
  const {all_product} = useContext(ShopContext);
  return (
    <div className='shop-category'>
      <img className='shopcategory-banner' src={props.banner} alt="" />
      <div className="shopcategory-indexSort">
        <p>
          <span>Showing 1-12</span> out of 36 products
        </p>
        <div className="shopcategory-sort">
          Sort by <img src={dropdown_icon} alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="shopcategory-products">
        {all_product.map((item,i) => {
          if (props.category === item.category) {
            return <Item key={i} id={item.id} name={item.name} image={item.image} new_price={item.new_price} old_price={item.old_price} />;
          } else {
            return null;
          }
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ShopCategory
```

## App.jsx

```
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';
import { Navbar } from './Components/Navbar/Navbar';
import { BrowserRouter as Router,Routes,Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import ShopCategory from './Pages/ShopCategory';
import { Product } from './Pages/Product';
import { Shop } from './Pages/Shop';
import { LoginSignup } from './Pages/LoginSignup';
import {Cart} from './Pages/Cart';
import { Footer } from './Components/Footer/Footer';
import men_banner from './Components/Assets/banner_mens.png'
import women_banner from './Components/Assets/banner_women.png'
import kid_banner from './Components/Assets/banner_kids.png'

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Router>
      <Navbar/>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Shop/>}/>
        <Route path='/mens' element={<ShopCategory banner={men_banner}  category="mens"/>}/>
        <Route path='/womens' element={<ShopCategory banner={women_banner} category="womens"/>}/>
        <Route path='/kids' element={<ShopCategory banner={kid_banner} category="kids"/>}/>
        <Route path="/product" element={<Product/>}>
        <Route path=":productId" element={<Product/>}/>
        </Route>
        <Route path='/cart' element={<Cart/>}/>
        <Route path='/login' element={<LoginSignup/>}/>
        </Routes> 
        <Footer/>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I need to show the contents of my `all_product` (item pass through context) in the each category when a category is selected.

Comment: I am not able to see usage of `ShopContextProvider` which you have exported . I believe it should be used in App.jsx like <ShopContextProvider><div>...rest of your code</div></ShopContextProvider>

Answer (score 0):

The `ShopContextProvider` would need to be rendered higher in the ReactTree in order for it to provide the `all_products` data to consumers like the `ShopCategory` component.

You have a couple options.

1. Render `ShopContextProvider` in the `App` around the routes.

   ```
   function App() {
     return (
       <div>
         <Router>
           <Navbar />
           <ShopContextProvider> // <-- provide Shop context to subReactTree
             <Routes>
               <Route path='/' element={<Shop />} />
               <Route
                 path='/mens'
                 element={<ShopCategory banner={men_banner} category="mens" />} 
               />
               <Route
                 path='/womens'
                 element={<ShopCategory banner={women_banner} category="womens" />}
               />
               <Route
                 path='/kids'
                 element={<ShopCategory banner={kid_banner} category="kids" />}
               />
               <Route path="/product" element={<Product />}>
                 <Route path=":productId" element={<Product />} />
               </Route>
               <Route path='/cart' element={<Cart />} />
               <Route path='/login' element={<LoginSignup />} />
             </Routes> 
             <Footer />
           </ShopContextProvider>
         </Router>
       </div>
     );
   }
   ```
2. Create a layout route component specific to the "shop" routes that can pass the `all_products` down via the `Outlet` component's context.

   ShopLayout

   ```
   import React from "react";
   import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
   import all_product from "../Components/Assets/all_product";

   const ShopLayout = () => {
     return <Outlet context={{ all_product }} />
   }

   export default ShopLayout;
   ```

   Use the `useOutletContext` hook to access the provided outlet context value.

   ShopCategory

   ```
   import React from 'react';
   import { useOutletContext } from 'react-router-dom';
   import './CSS/ShopCategory.css';
   import { ShopContext } from "../Context/ShopContext"
   import dropdown_icon from '../Components/Assets/dropdown_icon.png';
   import { Item } from '../Components/Item/Item';

   const ShopCategory = (props) => {
     const { all_product } = useOutletContext();

     return (
       <div className='shop-category'>
         <img className='shopcategory-banner' src={props.banner} alt="" />
         <div className="shopcategory-indexSort">
           <p>
             <span>Showing 1-12</span> out of 36 products
           </p>
           <div className="shopcategory-sort">
             Sort by <img src={dropdown_icon} alt="" />
           </div>
         </div>
         <div className="shopcategory-products">
           {all_product.map((item,i) => {
             if (props.category === item.category) {
               return <Item key={i} id={item.id} name={item.name} image={item.image} new_price={item.new_price} old_price={item.old_price} />;
             } else {
               return null;
             }
           })}
         </div>
       </div>
     );
   }
   ```

   App

   ```
   function App() {
     return (
       <div>
         <Router>
           <Navbar />
           <Routes>
             <Route path='/' element={<Shop />} />
             <Route element={<ShopLayout />}> // <-- provides all_product data
               <Route
                 path='/mens'
                 element={<ShopCategory banner={men_banner} category="mens" />} 
               />
               <Route
                 path='/womens'
                 element={<ShopCategory banner={women_banner} category="womens" />}
               />
               <Route
                 path='/kids'
                 element={<ShopCategory banner={kid_banner} category="kids" />}
               />
             </Route>
             <Route path="/product" element={<Product />}>
               <Route path=":productId" element={<Product />} />
             </Route>
             <Route path='/cart' element={<Cart />} />
             <Route path='/login' element={<LoginSignup />} />
           </Routes> 
           <Footer />
         </Router>
       </div>
     );
   }
   ```